# Angular Pipe not working on child routes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I have a very simple Pipe in Angular 5

```
import { Pipe, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: "default"
})
@Injectable()
export class DefaultPipe {
    transform(value: string, fallback: string): string {
        let image = "";
        if (value) {
            image = value;
        } else {
            image = fallback;
        }
        return image;
    }
}
```

and I use it in a very simple way just for demonstration

```
<div>
    {{ 'somthing' | default }}
</div>
```

I have also added in provider section in app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        DefaultPipe // <-- Here
    ],
    imports: [
        ....
    ],
    providers: [
        ....
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

when you use it in an normal component such as

> app.component.html

it works fine, but if you use it in a component which is used in a child route it gives this error:

> compiler.js:486 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: The pipe
>   'default' could not be found ("
>
> {{[ERROR ->] 'somthing' | default }} "): ng:///AppRoutingModule/LoginComponent.html@75:6
>       at syntaxError (compiler.js:486)
>       at TemplateParser.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse
>   (compiler.js:24674)
>       at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:34629)
>       at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate
>   (compiler.js:34604)
>       at compiler.js:34505
>       at Set.forEach ()
>       at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents
>   (compiler.js:34505)
>       at compiler.js:34375
>       at Object.then (compiler.js:475)
>       at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents
>   (compiler.js:34374)

**To Solve:**

I added this module as *share.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { DefaultPipe } from './core/pipes/default.pipe';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [DefaultPipe],
    exports: [DefaultPipe]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

and used it in 2 places, one in *app.module.ts*:

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
],
imports: [
    ...
    // other modules
    ...
    SharedModule
],
providers: [
    ....
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

})
export class AppModule { }

and one in *route.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ....
    ],
    imports: [
        ....
        SharedModule
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule,
    ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: could you please add the module in which you declare the `LoginComponent`?

Comment: Why vote-down? you put all the effort to solve a problem with many explains and here you go, you get a vote-down, THANKS SO MUCH !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to use the `Injectable` decorator on the pipe, so you can remove that.

Furthermore, as already suggested in other answers, I would recommend you to explicitely implement the `PipeTransform` interface in order to be consistent with the pipe API.

> compiler.js:486 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: The pipe 'default' could not be found ("
>
> {{[ERROR ->] 'somthing' | default }} "): ng:///AppRoutingModule/LoginComponent.html@75:6 at syntaxError (compiler.js:486)

is basically saying that your pipe wasnt neither declared or imported in the module, in which`LoginComponent` is declared.

The simplest and cleanest solution would be to declare/export the pipe inside of a new NgModule class, that you can then import into every module that declares a component that uses the pipe. For example:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [DefaultPipe],
  exports: [DefaultPipe]
})
export class DefaultPipeModule{}

@NgModule({
  imports: [DefaultPipeModule],
  declarations: [LoginComponent]
})
export class FooModule {}

@NgModule({
  imports: [DefaultPipeModule],
  declarations: [FooComponent] // fooComponent also uses the default pipe, so we need to import its module
})
export class SomeOtherModule{}
```

Comment: I do not know why they gave you a down-vote, but your suggestion actually was the right one and it did solve my issue. I added a share module and used it in my route module and app module and it worked. Thanks

Comment: @EhsanZargarErshadi would you mind adding the information that I requested in a comment on your question? just to make sure that your question could help others

Comment: this worked only after adding exports: [LoginComponent] to the 2nd module. otherwise errors

Answer (score 5):

The best practice for creating helper components, pipes or directives is to create a `SharedModule` and put that stuff inside.

Components, Directives and Pipes don't work like services. A service you can inject it in the AppModule's services array and that will work for children too.

A Pipe, Directive or Component you have to declare them in an NgModule and then import it where you need it, because they can **ONLY belong to 1 Module**. *(But that module can be imported as many times as you want!)*

Therefore, the best thing you could do is to create a `SharedModule` with the following:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ ... ],
  declarations: [ DefaultPipe ],
  exports: [ DefaultPipe ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

And then in `AppModule` you import `SharedModule` like this:

```
imports: [ SharedModule ]
```

And now, if you want to use it in your LoginComponent or in any other part of your application, you import your `SharedModule` in the module for that component.

Answer (score 0):

Reference : [here](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes)

## Custom pipe:

First of all, no @Injectable() since it's not a service that you'll define in the constructor.
Then, you need to import the `PipeTransform` provided in the `'@angular/core'` and implements it.

Example:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: "default"
})

export class DefaultPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string, fallback: string): string {
        let image = "";
        if (value) {
            image = value;
        } else {
            image = fallback;
        }
        return image;
    }
}
```